# Hibernate: Cannot find by UUID

Tags: spring, hibernate, uuid

Im trying to use UUID's as ids for my database but I simply do not get it working.

First attempt was:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
private UUID id;
```

but this is generating some ugly byte code. So I added a type annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
private UUID id;
```

with this I get a character representation in my mysql database but querying the database using my repository:

```
public interface CommentsRepository extends CrudRepository<Comment, UUID> {

    Comment findById(final UUID imageId);
}
```

wont find any result - even if an entry with the given UUID exists it wont return the result.
Even if I use plain SQL directly on my database it wont find any result.

Is there something else I need to do to get UUID's working?

**EDIT**

Trying this:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;
}
```

and adding some default values:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CommentsSampleData implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CommentsRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public CommentsSampleData(final CommentsRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        repository.save(new Comment());
        repository.save(new Comment());
        repository.save(new Comment());
        repository.save(new Comment());
    }
}
```

Results in the following table:

[image]

performing:

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id = 'b076a9f7-7e9e-4f5a-91f8-e66c7d076fac'
```

results in:

[image]

which means no result but there should be one. Using jpa also does not return anything.

Comment: Remove the `findById` method, that is already provided by Spring Data and this might interfere with the default one. Next to that when using the type you are using the db column needs to be a char or varchar and not something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this uuid annotation maybe:

```
@Id
GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID id;
```

This sample should work with `java.util.UUID`.

EDIT: I've read that you could run into problems with having a binary type set, so you could also try with explicitly setting it to a `char` uuid with:

```
@Type(type="uuid-char")
```

Comment: Alright, so going with the char type & changing the generator did it, my solution was almost there :)   glad it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 4):

It works with the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid4")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "uuid4")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was using the 2.1.212 version of H2 in memory database, I faced the same problem on my project.
I converted H2 version from 2.1.212 to 1.4.200 and it solved